# exception thrown when testing for blank space

Tags: java

I am stumped on this problem, I am trying to output the initials of first name and last name. I am testing for last names that have an "Mc"/ "Mac" / "O'Connell" and "O Connell" but the space is producing an error of type ---

full stack trace is:

```
run:
Please enter First name :colm
Please enter Last name o connell
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at Initials2.InitialsOutput(Initials2.java:22)
    at Initials2.main(Initials2.java:51)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

here is the code that throws an exception:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class InitialsTest {

    public static void InitialsOutput(String firstName, String lastName){

    // character array to hold the initials ex hellen walsh - output HW
        char charInitials[] = new char[5]; 
        charInitials[0] = firstName.charAt(0);

        // test for different name types to output initials
        // testing for mcMahon (which works)
        // testing for o'donnell (which works)
        // testing for macDonagh (which works)
        // testing for O Connell (which fails - throws exception)
        // the first test is for  a blank space (which fails) or an ' (which works)
        if (lastName.codePointAt(1) == '\u0020' | lastName.codePointAt(1) == 39){
        //if (lastName.codePointAt(1) == 32 | lastName.codePointAt(1) == 39){
        //if (lastName.codePointAt(1) == 0020 | lastName.codePointAt(1) == 39){
        //if (lastName.charAt(1) == ' ' | lastName.codePointAt(1) == 39){

            charInitials[1] = lastName.charAt(0);
            charInitials[2] = lastName.charAt(2); 
        } else if ((lastName.charAt(0) == 'm' | lastName.charAt(0) == 'M') 
                    & (lastName.charAt(1) == 'c' | lastName.charAt(1)== 'C')){
            charInitials[1] = lastName.charAt(0);
            charInitials[2] = lastName.charAt(2);
        } else if ((lastName.charAt(0) == 'm' | lastName.charAt(0) == 'M')
                    & (lastName.charAt(1) == 'a' | lastName.charAt(1)== 'A')
                    & (lastName.charAt(2) == 'c' | lastName.charAt(2)== 'C')){
            charInitials[1] = lastName.charAt(0);
            charInitials[2] = lastName.charAt(3);
        }
        else {
            charInitials[1] = lastName.charAt(0);
        }
       String initials;
       initials = new String (charInitials);

        System.out.println("Initials are : " + initials.toUpperCase());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter First name :");
            String first = userInput.next();
            System.out.print("Please enter Last name ");
            String last = userInput.next(); 
            InitialsOutput(first, last);                  
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace and indicate which line in your code fails. Also, look at `String.startsWith()` :-)

Comment: Add a runable example. So we can copy and paste it.

Comment: It looks like `lastname` has less than two characters

Comment: The obvious problem with your code is that you are doing indexed access on `lastName`; without ever checking the length of the incoming string. (you might want to put an assert in front of your code; just to make sure that the incoming string length is >= 4). And by the way: this code is horrible. Such endless cascades of if then else turn "not maintainable" the second you close your editor. Better think of something else; for example regular expressions. Or at least: "upper case" your input; to at laest save all compares with lower case characters.

Comment: As a word of advice, avoid unicode literals in favor of `' '` and `'\''`

Comment: the '\'' works, thanks for that change, but the ' ' is still giving me the same issue. thanks for help. i have added the full runnable code so you can see where the error occurs. the last name "o connell" is an example of where it gives the error

Comment: Remarks. For English/Scottish you may better stay with `char` as a code point may be 2 chars. Also java is not NUL terminated as C/C++, so charInitials as `char[]` is unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `Scanner.next()` which breaks your last name into 2 tokens: `o` and `connell`. The method `InitialsOutput` is called with `firstName = colm` and `lastName = o`. That's why `lastName.codePointAt(1)` gives you the error.

Changing `userInput.next();` to `userInput.nextLine();` should do the trick.

Comment: brilliant thanks, i would never have got that in a million years. now to change the program to cater for this and the other recommended alterations

Comment: *"It's because you're using Scanner"* No, it is  because he uses `next` instead of `nextLine`. The scanner itself  is not the problem. After the edit: yes, that is better :).

Comment: @Tom Thanks! I realized that just in time